# Immunity crashes on start

Tags: immunity-debugger

First off, I hope this is the right place to ask this question, if not please let me know where I should ask it.

I have a Windows XP sp2 VM (fresh install with no updates), with Python and immunity installed.

When I try and launch immunity, I see a brief view of the main window, then it closes. I get no errors and nothing in the Windows event viewer.

I am using the latest version of immunity from their website.

Is there anywhere else I can look for the cause of the problem? Is this a known issue? Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: You can try this answer, although I have never experienced this on xp: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12164/14595

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same issue but my case was a little bit different.  I had Python 3.5 installed on my Windows 7 laptop.  Immunity would open and then immediately close.  I installed Python 2.7 and, when I launched Immunity Debugger, it came up perfectly.  So, in addition the your environmental variables, also be careful about which version of Python you're running!